# A cross-browser javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I have this JavaScript that let me scroll the page up / down by clicking on the top / bottom of the page.

```
$(function() {
$("#next").on("click", function() {
    $("body").animate({"scrollTop": window.scrollY + (window.innerHeight - 60)}, 100);
    return false;
});
}); 

$(function() {
$("#previous").on("click", function() {
    $("body").animate({"scrollTop": window.scrollY - (window.innerHeight - 60)}, 100);
    return false;
});
});
```

Have a look at the JSFIDDLE here:
https://jsfiddle.net/cztqjwb2/3/

Any idea how to make it cross-browser?

Answer (score 3):

Some browsers attach the scrollbar to the body, other to the `html` element.

You'd make it cross browser like this

```
$("html, body").animate( ....
```

To make it work in older IE as well, you have to replace `scrollY` with something, jQuery seems like the obvious choice

```
$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - 60
}, 100);
```